# test for convergence or divergence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, computational-mathematics

So I am looking at the following series:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{{ln(n)+n^p+r^n+n!}\over{n^n-n!-r^n-n^p-ln(n)}}$$

Before testing, I wanted to look at some series that I can compare this to but haven't been able to think of one yet. Any suggestion?

Comment: Identify the dominant terms in numerator and denominator.

Comment: I kind of got it, I'm curious to see different approaches, so obviously the dominant term on nmrt is $n!$ and on dnmnt is $n^n$, can I say that there exists a number $C\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n^n-$(stuff)$>(1/C)n^n$?

Comment: You can say that, but in order to use it, you need to prove it. It's not difficult to show, however.

Comment: How would you suggest doing it without proving the above result?

Comment: Use equivalents.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** If $r>1$,
$$\ln n=o(n^p),\enspace n^p=o(r^n),\enspace r^n=o(n!),\enspace n!=o(n^n),$$
hence the numerator is equivalent at $+\infty$ to $n!$, and the denominator to $n^n$.

Then use *Stirling's formula*, and apply the root test.